# Google Analytics JS-Function turns out empty?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, implementation

I'm trying to implement Google-Analytics and am having a strange outcome:

on loading the page, this script-part:

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

is replaced by this:

```
(function() )();
```

naturally resulting in a syntax-error.

I tried to remove Jquery from the page (as I read somewhere this causes problems) but it didn't help...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the HTML/JS structure of your page? See, this snippet attempts to create a script with external src element (to load that GA bigger script) AND insert it before the first `<script>` element in your page. It works quite well, when snippet itself is just a <script> placed somewhere at the end of `<body>`. But what exactly should happen when it's invoked _after_ the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Well, the documentation says, it should be inserted right before the closing </head>-Tag. That's what I did.
I'm basically aware what the snippet does. It's just a little puzzling that it's emptying itself :)

Comment: @raina77ow -- as of the newer asynch version of GA, it's correct to add the GA script in the head section.  The recommendation to add it just before the closing body tag is no longer right (and will cause errors in some browsers for anything referencing the `_gaq` variable).  @Swissdude -- make sure to add the full contents of the `<script>` tag provided by GA, inline in the head of each page, not just the function itself.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that helped!
Forgot to add it to one page...